# Android: Example for AccountManager class method getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures

Tags: android, accountmanager

I had gone through the android doc on AccountManager and its Methods. I could understand the getAccounts() & getAccountsByType(). But i couldnot understand the **getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures()..** Is there any example or tutorial for this fn.

Thanks in Advance